# No se me actualizan los estilos css en django

Tags: python, css, django

llevo trabajando en un proyecto desde hace aproximadamente un mes, y de un dia para otro django ya no me reproduce los cambios realizados en mi fichero de estilos css, he probado a actualizar el navegador, he probado distintos navegadores, he borrado la cache de estos y no hay manera de que vuelva a ejecutar los cambios del css

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: Y como te podemos ayudar si no sabemos lo que haces?

Comment: entiendo, de todos modos lo estoy logrando por mi cuenta, pero en el proceso me acaba de dar un error porque he puesto tanto el STACIFILES_DIRS. Como el STATIC_ROOT. señalando a la misma ruta. y me salta el error "?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting." Queria saber que diferencia hay entre el STATIC_ROOT Y EL STATICFILES_DIRS. Y porque me da ese error

Comment: Sería bueno ver tu codigo

Comment: perdoname, pero no manejo muy bien el stackoverflow. Hechale un ojo a la edicion de la pregunta, en este momento esa es mi configuracion de los archivos estaticos, si le quito el static_root no me da error y no va mal pero quiero saber de que va esa configuracion

Comment: Antes de continuar te recomiendo leer [ask] y pasar por el [tour] para que no tengas problemas al hacer la pregunta.

Comment: gracias, le hechare un ojo en cuanto tenga un poco de tiempo

Answer (score 2):

Cada vez que cambias el archivo CSS y quieres ver los cambios actualiza el navegador con `Ctrl`+`F5`. Esto vacía el caché guardado. Se puede decir que es como refrescar la página desde cero. Espero haberte ayudado.

Otro posible error es que no estés importando de manera correcta tu `style` en el template. Verifica la url que le estás pasando.

Comment: esto debe ser un comentario y tienes la suficiente reputación para poner uno

Comment: Es obvio que si lo puse como respuesta fue porque en su momento (hace 6 meses) no tenía la rep suficiente.

Comment: jaja lo siento, no había pensado en eso, solo ingora mi comentario y disculpa mi error